# extracting list of detections from YOLOv3

Tags: artificial-intelligence, embedded-linux, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I'm working on an object detection app using YOLOv3 I retrained the model to detect two classes and it was done successfully so far thanks to the creators of the Repo.
Now I have to deploy the model on a jetson nano kit and it should run continuously and extract the list of detections specifying classes, confidence and bounding boxes coordinates then I should do some processing on the previously mentioned parameters then send it using any communication protocol to another ECU, anyway How to extract the mentioned parameters from YOLOv3 and make that code run continuously

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Python script for YOLOv3 detection you will encounter this part in the script:

```
detections = darknet.detect_image(netMain, metaMain, darknet_image, thresh=0.25)
image = cvDrawBoxes(detections, frame_resized)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Here detections should be a dictionary or an array of some sort (it varries across different implementations). It should contain *detected_classes* , *number_of_detections*, *confidence_scores* and *bounding_boxes*. You can modify the code to extract whatever you want. Code above is from [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/darknet_video.py) repo. I also used YOLOv3 for continuous image detection. It was suppose to tell if a picture contains a person or not.

**Note:** If i remember correctly in C++ scripts of YOLOv3 should be a similar part like I mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a specific way of using a python script for YOLOv3?

Comment: If you take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) there is detailed explanation for everything you might have in mind

Comment: could you please refer to this part in the repository